# Add custom metadata fields for DAM assets in a particular folder

Tags: metadata, aem, dam

I created custom metadata fields for DAM Assets in CQ 5.6.1 using the steps detailed [here](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/dam/how_to_edit_metadata.html#Creating%20New%20Metadata%20Property%20for%20Assets/%22here%22). However, as described in the document, these changed fields are available for *ALL* assets in the DAM.

I need these metadata fields to be made available to only a specific folder, say `/content/dam/foo` instead of every asset.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The link now goes to an old documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge, there is no straight forward way to achieve this but there is one trick to handle this.

AEM DAM has the notion of meta schema editors. These editors are tied to asset file type, meaning - jpeg, mov, etc. For an asset MIME type, you can define the meta data and its associated form.

AEM 6.0 provides choral UI interface to achieve this --
http://localhost:4502/libs/dam/gui/content/metadataschemaeditor/schemalist.html/dam/content/schemaeditors/forms

Am not aware of any such interface in AEM 5.6.1. The nodes tied to this are at `/libs/dam/content/asseteditors/image/jpeg/formitems`. You could overlay them at `/apps` to add the required metadata.

Coming to the question, the trick is to add the file type into your dam content hierarchy. Example - /content/dam/jpeg/foo, /content/dam/png/foo, etc. This way, you would get different metadata for different folders of the dam.

Adobe recommends this approach as AEM 6.0 introduced the concept of processing profiles which you could attach to folders. This way, your different file types could get different treatments.

Comment: Hi Siva, thanks for your response. However, when I have two folders, such as /content/dam/jpeg/foo1 and /content/dam/jpeg/foo2, I find that the properties for both are the same. 

I was looking for a way to ensure that jpg images under two different folders, foo1 and foo2 have different properties, and not just different properties for different asset types.

Comment: I doubt if it's doable.